# How to fire browser back button event when I press a button inside the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching

I want to load the previous page without postback when I click on a button in the current page.?

The same event should occur when we click on browser back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
$('#mybtn').click(function(){
    history.go(-1);
});
```

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap as your UI framework,then

<a class="btn btn-primary " onclick="window.history.back();"> Back </a>

This takes you to the previous page.